# How to test web app performance from a variety of geographical regions?

Tags: performance, web

I have a web app in Canada and it works well.

I have a co-worker in Arizona who says it takes 10 seconds for the web app to load, and even longer for two images.

Is there an easy way to test the performance of the web application from a variety of geographical regions?

Any suggestions are useful!!

Answer (score 0):

Online tools such as pingdom http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/ allows you to choose the geographic location to test from.

Google analytics also has a site speed feature allowing you to see site load times by the visitor's geographic region if you wish to filter by that.
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1205784?hl=en